# Creating non visual-component vs2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I switched to **VS2012 and C#** this month from **Delphi** but I'm having some problem.

I started creating a Class that talk with a `PLC` via `Serial port`, it works fine but I would like to convert it to a `non-visual component`, so I can just drag and drop it into a form instead of having to add all the **.cs file** that I use.

I've already created some `UserControl` but in this case I just want a **non-visual component** (so I should inherit from **component**) like a timer for example.

I've looked around on google but I just can't find anything that relate to that or that explains me how to do it. Anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: you want to drag and drop a timer onto a form.  I don't quite get it.

Comment: No sorry, I want to convert the class I created into a non visual component that appears on the toolbox so I can drag-and-drop it into a form and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not encapsulate your functionality in a class, and add a code reference to this class?

**Update**

Seems you can add a custom dll to the toolbox, and decorate it like this.

Disclaimer, I have not tested this...

[ToolboxBitmap(@"D:\targetbitmap.bmp")]

```
public class CustomGridView : GridView
{
```

Comment: I'm still new to this but I suppose that's what I did, I created my class "Serial" which take care of all the internal stuff that I need to  use the serial port and expose only a couple of function like connect() and read() then I add a using "Serial" on my form. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, instead of creating a visual control, just use the class you created then. Instantiate an object from it, and call its functions. This still won't add the toolbox visual element, like a timer, but its non-visual, and does what you want?

Comment: Well yea I did that at it works, but this approch seems cluttered to me. Instead of having to add the files to my project every time I have to use that class (and mind it's a specialized thing that works only with just a type of PLC so I already created more than 5 different classes and more will follow once I finish converting my stuff from delphi to c#) I just drop a component in the form and start coding right away. Beside since i'm still new, this seems like a good opporunity to learn to create component opposed to UserControl.

Comment: Maybe you are looking to create a dll from your class?

Comment: Would that add a component on the toolbox ?

Comment: Nope, but once again, adding a reference to your project, will make it act the way you want, in your code. But I think I understand that you are looking for the "convenience" of dragging and dropping it on. It can be done, but I'm not sure how. Maybe someone will come along and help you out.

Comment: Indeed, anyway I will look into creating a dll like you suggested to see while I wait to see if anyone answer.  Thank you for your time.